# How to send the same value in emit observer?

Tags: angular

I have output value:

```
@Output() addChanged = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

I emit value as:

```
this.addChanged.emit(true);
```

It is always true value.

So, in component I try to listen this value like:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.isAdding);
  }
```

Problem is that I send always the same value `true`, therefore the second time `ngAfterViewInit` does not work for me.

Comment: I thin'k you use rxjs Subject replace with EventEmitter variable. please check https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject

Comment: Can you elaborate this `therefore the second time ngAfterViewInit does not work for me.`?

Comment: why don't you create listener method and use it in html template like `(addChange)=listenerMethod($event)`?

Comment: we definetly need more info about ur code. Post HTML and your component pls

Comment: I use `EventEmitter`

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks, read about `ngAfterViewInit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the Angular source code for the `EventEmitter` you find that Angular is actually triggering the `super.next(value)` every time you calling the `emit(value)` function. That means you'll get the most updated value on the parent subscriber.

Source:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/event_emitter.ts#L85

All you need to do is to add a function handler to your custom event, something like:

```
<my-child-component (addChanged)="handlerFunction($event)">
```

And in your typescript file:

```
handlerFunction(value){
 console.log(value)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your html where u listen to the output, do this:

```
<your-component (addChanged)=addChanged($event)></your-component>
```

Any time u emit the value from your childcomponent the listener function addChange($event) receives the emitted value. In your parent component.ts

```
addChanged(event: any) {
  console.log(event); // Here u receive the true value emitted from the childcomponent
}
```

I already answered such a question here: [clear-concept-of-eventemitter-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51298115/clear-concept-of-eventemitter-class/51300001#51300001)